# Failing to set CA:FALSE when signing usercert with openssl via php

Tags: php, openssl, ca

When signing CSR:s with my custom CA, I do not want my clients to be able to sign other certificates with the obtained certificate. I understand that one way of doing this is to set `CA:FALSE` under `X509v3 Basic Constraints:`. But I fail to set this even though my openssl.cnf has this set under `[ usr_cert ]`. What an I missing?

Here is the code that executes:

```
    $cnf = ['config' => $cnf_path];

    $cnf['digest_alg'] = 'sha1';
    $cnf['x509_extentions'] = 'usr_cert';

    $usercert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, $cacert, $privkey, 365, $cnf);

    openssl_x509_export($usercert, $certout);
```

Here is my openssl.cnf: http://pastebin.com/4fWdErN7

Comment: The CONF file looks OK to me. My guess is PHP is not passing the CONF file to OpenSSL or there's a problem with `cnf_path`. Can you confirm PHP is generating a `-config` option for OpenSSL command, and that `cnf_path` is valid?